# How to get values from object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, json.net

my Json code is

```
ListOrderDetails.push({ // Add Order Details to array                  
                "OrderType": OrderType,
                "CaseNumber": CaseNumber,
                "OrderNumber": OrderNumber,
                "OrderStatus": OrderStatus,
                "Reason": Reason,
                "Coments": Coments
            });

var Params = { "Geo": Geography, "GeoId": GeographyID, "CountryCode": CountryCode, "Segment": Segment, "SubsegmentID": SubSegmentID, "OrderDetails": ListOrderDetails };
        //var Params = { "Geo": Geography, "GeoId": GeographyID, "CountryCode": CountryCode, "Segment": Segment, "SubsegmentID": SubSegmentID };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyDataVer1.aspx/SaveManualEntry",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(Params),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("xhr : " + xhr);
                alert("textStatus : " + textStatus);
                alert("errorThrown " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

c# webmethod is

```
[WebMethod]
public static int SaveManualEntry(string Geo, int GeoId, string CountryCode,
                                  string Segment, string SubsegmentID, 
                                  object[] OrderDetails)
{

    try
    {
        int TotalOrderCount = 0;
        int Successcount = 0;               
        return Successcount;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

How to get values from the Object orderDetails. I cant use indexing.

Comment: Your formatting is atrocious. Please make use of the proper editing tools and the preview **before** you post a question.

Comment: yes ..sure ..sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: No need to apologise. Just do it properly next time. =)

Comment: Why are you receiving an `object[]` and not creating a type representing your entities?

Comment: you can also use linq to change the format

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection:

```
foreach(var order in orderDetails)
{
    string orderType = (string)order.GetType().GetProperty("OrderType").GetValue(order);
    // other properties
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You first need to create an order detail object:

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public string OrderType { get; set; }
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string Coments { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your web method to this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static int SaveManualEntry(string Geo, int GeoId, string CountryCode,
                                  string Segment, string SubsegmentID, 
                                  List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails)
{

    try
    {
        int TotalOrderCount = 0;
        int Successcount = 0;               
        return Successcount;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Which accepts a `List<OrderDetails>` instead.